# Inferring a characteristic of a ratio of functions from the ratio of their derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, polynomials

This is a strange one, but I need help trying to understand whether there is any logic behind this or not.

Given $\frac {f(\sqrt{2})}{g(\sqrt{2})}=2$, and $\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}>2$ for all $x>\sqrt{2}$, can we infer that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are monotone increasing polynomials, that $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}>2$ for all $x>\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Note that $ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'$ see if you find something useful from this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating $f'>2g'$ from $\sqrt2$ to $x$:
$$f(x)-2g(\sqrt2)=f(x)-f(\sqrt2)>2g(x)-2g(\sqrt2),$$
$$f(x)>2g(x).$$

Comment: I like this a lot actually. This definitely makes sense to me (though I have never integrated both sides of an inequality before); thank you very much!

Comment: Think in the geometric meaning of definite integrals.

Comment: I guess that is true. As long as the domain is defined (which it is), than the area under $f'(x)$'s curve would naturally be greater than that of $2g'(x)$'s curve, given the assumptions.